# How can I get the the waiting times for access or failing in a function that is locked by threads?

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading

I'm using a function to add some values in an Dynamic Array (I know that I could use a list but it's a requirement that I must use an Array).

Right now everything is working but I need to know when a thread fails adding a value (because it's locked and to save that time) and when it adds it (I think when it adds, I already have it as you can see in the function Add.

Insert Data:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showMessage(numericUpDown5.Value.ToString());
    showMessage(numericUpDown6.Value.ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(numericUpDown6.Value.ToString()); i++)
    {
        ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(insertDataSecure);
        new Thread(start).Start();
    }
}

private void insertDataSecure()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(numericUpDown5.Value.ToString()); i++)
        sArray.addSecure(i);

    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Finished data inserted, you can check the result in: {0}", Path.Combine(
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
"times.txt")), "Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Function to Add:

```
private object padLock = new object();
public void addSecure(int value)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    string values = "";

    lock (padLock)
    {
        try
        {
            if (array == null)
            {
                this.size = 1;
                Resize(this.size);

                array[0] = value;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                count++;
                if (size == count)
                {
                    size *= 2;
                    Resize(size);
                }

                array[count - 1] = value;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("It was impossible to insert, try again later.", "insert");
        }

        values=String.Format("Element {0}, Time taken: {1}ms", value.ToString(), sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        sw.Stop();
        saveFile(values);
    }
```

Sorry for asking this question but I have read different articles and this is the last one that I tried to use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw.aspx but when I tried to implement in my code finally crashed in an strange error.

Comment: One does not simply use message box out of the UI thread. If you target in .Net 4.0, use async and await pairs, or using callback structure Action.BeginInvoke()

Comment: The MessageBox is part of the Windows Forms, it appears when the insertions finished. Do you have any example to check because I couldn't find a good example and as I said, right know I just need to know when an insert wasn't done and the time that it had that fail.

Comment: The code in insertDataSecure() is running in a new thread out of UI thread. All UI component access will cause error i.e. MessageBox

Comment: It works, I have already tried. I don't have a bug running it my problem is to know when it cannot add a value while it's adding other from another thread. I don't have any exception right know.

Comment: See Await / Async if you using .Net 4.5 http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/hh191443.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I might not completely understand the question. It sounds like you want to know how long it takes between the time the thread starts and when it actually acquires the lock. But in that case, the thread does not actually *fail* to add a value; it is simply delayed some period of time.

On the other hand, you do have an exception handler, so presumably there's some scenario you expect where the `Resize()` method can throw an exception (but you should catch *only* those exceptions you expect and know you can handle…a bare `catch` clause is not a good idea, though the harm is mitigated somewhat by the fact that you do throw *some* exception the exception handler). So I can't help but wonder if *that* is the failure you're talking about.

That said, assuming the former interpretation is correct – that you want to time how long it takes to acquire the lock – then the following change to your code should do that:

```
public void addSecure(int value)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    string values = "";

    lock (padLock)
    {
        // Save the current timer value here
        TimeSpan elapsedToAcquireLock = sw.Elapsed;

        try
        {
            if (array == null)
            {
                this.size = 1;
                Resize(this.size);

                array[0] = value;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                count++;
                if (size == count)
                {
                    size *= 2;
                    Resize(size);
                }

                array[count - 1] = value;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("It was impossible to insert, try again later.", "insert");
        }

        sw.Stop();
        values = string.Format(
            "Element {0}, Time taken: for lock acquire: {1}ms, for append operation: {2}ms",
             value.ToString(),
             elapsedToAcquireLock.TotalMilliseconds,
             sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds - elapsedToAcquireLock.TotalMilliseconds);
        saveFile(values);
    }
}
```

That will display the individual times for the sections of code: acquiring the lock, and then actually adding the value to the array (i.e. the latter *not* including the time taken to acquire the lock).

If that's not actually what you are trying to do, please edit your question so that it is more clear.

Comment: Hi! I'd like to know if for example 2 threads try to access at the same time to the function and of course they are trying to insert in it, because it's locked just one of them can insert right? I need to know that time when function failed trying to add something because it was locked.

Comment: "I need to know that time when function failed trying to add something because it was locked" -- that makes no sense. Just because some thread has the lock, that does _not_ cause any other thread to _fail_ to try to add something. The other thread simply waits until the lock is available, and then it acquires it. There is _no_ time that the function failed; it will still succeed...it just takes a little longer.